# Geoflutterfire within-function shall simply return all existing values in the firestore db, and not listen forever

Tags: flutter, geo

All examples I see for the within-function of geoflutterfire listen to the resulting stream, and set a marker in a map as soon as a new location in the DB appears. I.e. the stream is continously monitoring the DB in realtime for new locations, never coming to an end. I, however, want nothing but to read all existing locations in the DB, and then work on the resulting list. When I call await stream.forEach(), I find that the await never returns. Similarly, an await stream.length() does never return. I think a stream.listen would also not help, because there is no "last" event. The only solution I could find is:

```
    Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream = geo.collection(collectionRef: collRef)
          .within(center: center, radius: radius, field: "latlng");
    stream.timeout(Duration(seconds: 2), onTimeout: (eventSink) {
            print("timed out");
            eventSink.close();
          }).forEach(() {...});
```

that stops waiting for more locations after e.g. 2 seconds. Is there another solution? Am I completely mislead?

Answer (score 0):

I programmed around this issue, by not using Streams, and calling Query.get. As I did not want to get all locations in a radius, but in a box, I added an extension "withinBox" to Geoflutterfire, like this:

```
import 'package:geoflutterfire/geoflutterfire.dart';
// ignore: implementation_imports
import 'package:geoflutterfire/src/models/DistanceDocSnapshot.dart';
// ignore: implementation_imports
import 'package:geoflutterfire/src/Util.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

// like within, but sw/ne instead of circle/radius
extension GeoBox on GeoFireCollectionRef {
  static Query _collectionReference;

  Query _queryPoint(String geoHash, String field) {
    final end = '$geoHash~';
    final temp = _collectionReference;
    return temp.orderBy('$field.geohash').startAt([geoHash]).endAt([end]);
  }

  Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> withinBox(Query collRef, String field,
      double minlat, double maxlat, double minlon, double maxlon) async {
    _collectionReference = collRef;
    GeoFirePoint center =
        GeoFirePoint((minlat + maxlat) / 2, (minlon + maxlon) / 2);
    double radius = center.distance(lat: maxlat, lng: maxlon);

    final precision = Util.setPrecision(radius);
    final centerHash = center.hash.substring(0, precision);
    final area = GeoFirePoint.neighborsOf(hash: centerHash)..add(centerHash);

    Iterable<Future<List<DistanceDocSnapshot>>> queries = area.map((hash) {
      final tempQuery = _queryPoint(hash, field);
      return tempQuery.get().then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
        return querySnapshot.docs
            .map((element) => DistanceDocSnapshot(element, null))
            .toList();
      });
    });

    List<DocumentSnapshot> filtered = [];
    await Future.wait(
        queries.map((Future<List<DistanceDocSnapshot>> query) async {
      List<DistanceDocSnapshot> list = await query;
      var mappedList = list.map((DistanceDocSnapshot distanceDocSnapshot) {
        // split and fetch geoPoint from the nested Map
        final fieldList = field.split('.');
        var geoPointField =
            distanceDocSnapshot.documentSnapshot.data()[fieldList[0]];
        final GeoPoint geoPoint = geoPointField['geopoint'];
        bool insideBox = geoPoint.latitude > minlat &&
            geoPoint.latitude < maxlat &&
            geoPoint.longitude > minlon &&
            geoPoint.longitude < maxlon;
        distanceDocSnapshot.distance = insideBox ? 0 : 9999999;
        return distanceDocSnapshot;
      });

      final filteredList = mappedList
          .where((DistanceDocSnapshot doc) => doc.distance == 0)
          .toList();
      filtered.addAll(filteredList.map((element) => element.documentSnapshot));
    }));
    return filtered;
  }
}
```

This calls tempQuery.get(), where the original within() calls _createStream(tempQuery).
The code executes actually 9 queries: for the center square and 8 neighbor squares. Crucial for the performance is the "await Future.wait(queries.map())" call, that executes all 9 queries in parallel.

Although I am quite happy with this code, now that the timeout() has disappeared, I would still appreciate an answer for the original question.